# Has the Raspberry Pi already been used to build a proprietary product?

Tags: kiosk

In [an interview to Linux Voice](https://www.linuxvoice.com/a-man-with-his-fingers-in-many-millions-of-pies/), not long ago, [Eben Upton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eben_Upton) said:

> ***"You can build a business around [Raspberry Pi] because you can depend on them existing [...]"***

Hence, my question: Has the Raspberry Pi already been used to build a proprietary product?

Say, for example, a console running a piece of closed-source proprietary software in kiosk mode or anything else?

P.S.: Apart from [Eben Upton's own *Raspberry Pi Trading* business...](https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/08207441)

Comment: If you Google you should be able to find examples of Raspberry Pis embedded into products, media centres and such like.  I doubt there are many legal closed source products because most will be based on open source "viral" licenced software.

Comment: [This](http://embedded-computing.com/26496-raspberry-pi-goes-custom-for-industrial-commercial-applications/) looks like an interesting development. With a minimum order in the region of 3000 units then it's conceivable that there might be an industrial market for Pi-ish boards.

Comment: ...and the compute module was created specifically for customers to embed into their own products.

Comment: Just in case this isn't glaringly obvious, and without intending to imply anything about this particular case:  Consider what it really means when a salesperson/corporate rep/CEO/someone who is paid one way or another to promote a product says, "You can build a business around our product because you can depend on them existing..."  In a big picture literal sense, this could *never* be true for any product of any sort.  So the value and significance of it is obviously context dependent.

Comment: ...More generally, few  technology businesses are really 100% dependent on the existence of any particular component -- but the cost of redesigning/retooling/reprogramming etc. may vary greatly depending on the knowledge, skill, and foresight of those involved.  So this is somewhere between whimsical and nonsensical WRT real world relevance.   Also, tangentially: You introduced the term *proprietary* here which is not used once in the article you refer to.

Comment: It's also still a great prototyping board for a variety of applications. When you're actually selling a device at large scale, you'll probably have your own boards printed with an SOC on them.

Comment: Also check engineering university websites. Lots of capstone senior design (final year project) projects involve the creation of prototypes. A chunk of these always have some key Raspberry Pi integration. These projects can be sponsored by major companies.

Answer (score 4):

If you google around you'll find several. The first that comes to my mind is [slice](http://fiveninjas.com/). I would argue that it's not an optimal platform for a commercial product, but it's clearly possible and has been done.

Answer (score 3):

I was quite amused and surprised to find a Raspberry Pi sitting in the rack-mountable case for a PBX I recently bought— it's the [XorCom Spark CXS1000](https://xorcom.com/product/small-business-ip-pbx/).  It handles calls over VoIP and Analog phone lines for a small business.

You can see the Pi in the [PDF getting started guide](https://files.xorcom.com/techdocs/PM0661-Spark-CXS1000-Getting-Started-Guide.pdf) on the final page, the Pi is the board on the right (you can just make out the RaspberryPi logo)